# Can't display virtual console

Tags: command-line, 18.04, login, virtual-console

I got stuck on a login loop and to try to fix it, I need to access a terminal. I pressed `CTRL+ALT+F1-6` but the GUI just freezes and I don't get a terminal. If I `CTRL+ALT+F7`, I'm back to the GUI where I am locked.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you boot from a Live Media you can then maybe find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that it doesn't display the console, but it is still there.

Following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/1632344) answer (blindly) resolved my issue.